# Traefik 2 - Trying to configure my first container to use traefik

Tags: docker, https, docker-compose, traefik, portainer

Am a n00b to traefik & linux - have been following guides at smarthomebeginner trying to use traefik2 as a reverse proxy in docker on a synology NAS. To start me easy I'm trying to run portainer and access it securely via the traefik container.

I've got traefik2 up and running and I can connect to it's dashboard at traefik.mydomain.co.uk, and when I do my browser says the certificate is valid so looks like all running ok.

I've then added portainer to my docker compose and it appears to be working as when I send my browser to *LocalIP:9000* I get the portainer dashboard.

But when I visit portainer.mydomain.co.uk I get a 404 Error page not found.

I think the problem must be something to do with 'entry points' because when I visit my traefik dashboard, at the top of the page that it says there are entry points http(80) https(443) and traefik(8080). There appears to be no mention of a 9000.

I've tried adding some stuff under command: in my portainer section of the compose file but all that seems to do is stop the portainer from working even on the local IP!

Would anyone be able to look at my docker-compose file and point where I'm going wrong with this?

```
> version: "3.7"

########################### NETWORKS
networks:
  t2_proxy:
    external:
      name: t2_proxy
  default:
    driver: bridge

########################### SERVICES
services:
# All services / apps go below this line

# Traefik 2 - Reverse Proxy
  traefik:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:2.2.1 # the chevrotin tag refers to v2.2.x but introduced a breaking change in 2.2.2
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: # CLI arguments
      - --global.checkNewVersion=true
      - --global.sendAnonymousUsage=true
      - --entryPoints.http.address=:80
      - --entryPoints.https.address=:443
        # Allow these IPs to set the X-Forwarded-* headers - Cloudflare IPs: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/
      - --entrypoints.https.forwardedHeaders.trustedIPs=173.245.48.0/20,103.21.244.0/22,103.22.200.0/22,103.31.4.0/22,141.101.64.0/18,108.162.192.0/18,190.93.240.0/20,188.114.96.0/20,197.234.240.0/22,198.41.128.0/17,162.158.0.0/15,104.16.0.0/12,172.64.0.0/13,131.0.72.0/22
      - --entryPoints.traefik.address=:8080
      - --api=true
#      - --api.insecure=true
#      - --serversTransport.insecureSkipVerify=true
      - --log=true
      - --log.level=DEBUG # (Default: error) DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
      - --accessLog=true
      - --accessLog.filePath=/traefik.log
      - --accessLog.bufferingSize=100 # Configuring a buffer of 100 lines
      - --accessLog.filters.statusCodes=400-499
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - --providers.docker.defaultrule=Host(`{{ index .Labels "com.docker.compose.service" }}.$DOMAINNAME`)
      - --providers.docker.exposedByDefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=t2_proxy
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=false
      - --providers.file.directory=/rules # Load dynamic configuration from one or more .toml or .yml files in a directory.
#      - --providers.file.filename=/path/to/file # Load dynamic configuration from a file.
      - --providers.file.watch=true # Only works on top level files in the rules folder
#      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.caServer=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory # LetsEncrypt Staging Server - uncomment when testing
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.email=$CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.storage=/acme.json
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnsChallenge.provider=cloudflare
      - --certificatesResolvers.dns-cloudflare.acme.dnsChallenge.resolvers=1.1.1.1:53,1.0.0.1:53
    networks:
      t2_proxy:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.90.254 # You can specify a static IP
#    networks:
#      - t2_proxy
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 443
        published: 443
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
      - target: 8080
        published: 8080
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    volumes:
      - $DOCKERDIR/traefik2/rules:/rules 
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - $DOCKERDIR/traefik2/acme/acme.json:/acme.json 
      - $DOCKERDIR/traefik2/traefik.log:/traefik.log 
      - $DOCKERDIR/shared:/shared
    environment:
      - CF_API_EMAIL=$CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL
      - CF_API_KEY=$CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # HTTP-to-HTTPS Redirect
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=HostRegexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      # HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.rule=Host(`traefik.$DOMAINNAME`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls=true"
      #- "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.certresolver=dns-cloudflare" # Comment out this line after first run of traefik to force the use of wildcard certs
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[0].main=$DOMAINNAME"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[0].sans=*.$DOMAINNAME"
#      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[1].main=$SECONDDOMAINNAME" # Pulls main cert for second domain
#      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.tls.domains[1].sans=*.$SECONDDOMAINNAME" # Pulls wildcard cert for second domain
      ## Services - API
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.service=api@internal"
      ## Middlewares
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.middlewares=middlewares-basic-auth@file"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-rtr.middlewares=middlewares-rate-limit@file,middlewares-basic-auth@file" 

  # Portainer - WebUI for Containers
  portainer:
    container_name: portainer
    image: portainer/portainer:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - t2_proxy
    ports:
      - "$PORTAINER_PORT:9000"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - $DOCKERDIR/portainer/data:/data # Change to local directory if you want to save/transfer config locally
    environment:
      - TZ=$TZ
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      ## HTTP Routers
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-rtr.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-rtr.rule=Host(`portainer.$DOMAINNAME`)"
      ## Middlewares
      # - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-rtr.middlewares=chain-no-auth@file" # No Authentication
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-rtr.middlewares=middlewares-basic-auth@file" # Basic Authentication
      # - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-rtr.middlewares=chain-oauth@file" # Google OAuth 2.0
      # - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-rtr.middlewares=chain-authelia@file" # Authelia
      ## HTTP Services
      - "traefik.http.routers.portainer-rtr.service=portainer-svc"
      - "traefik.http.services.portainer-svc.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right about entrypoints:

```
  - --entryPoints.http.address=:80
  - --entryPoints.https.address=:443
```

You missed your entrypoint for port 9000

```
  - --entryPoints.http.address=:80
  - --entryPoints.https.address=:443
  - --entryPoints.portainer.address=:9000
```

But if you add 9000 it supposes you want to listen the 9000 port but it's probably not you want to do.

You want to go to your domain to 443 then be redirected to 9000.

If you publish the port 9000 it could resolve your problem

If you see here:

```
ports:
  - target: 80
    published: 80
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
  - target: 443
    published: 443
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
  - target: 8080
    published: 8080
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
```

You should add your port 9000 like

```
ports:
  - target: 80
    published: 80
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
  - target: 443
    published: 443
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
  - target: 8080
    published: 8080
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
  - target: 9000
    published: 9000
    protocol: tcp
    mode: host
```

Hope you found the answer somehow before my answer.